# Install multiple apps from my app in just one click

Tags: android, installation

Suppose I have a string array of apps' package names and I want to install them directly from my app in one click (let's say on button click)

User clicks the button and it directly goes to Play Store's MultiInstall activity. Something like this:

[image: click here]

I checked the logcat when we select some apps from 'ALL' tab of 'My apps & games' and when we click "Install" it directly starts MultiInstallActivity of Play Store app (`com.android.vending`).

Answer (score 1):

It might not go quite as far as you need it to but following will open app for given package name in Play Store app (user still needs to click "Install")

```
public static void installApp(Context context, String appPackageName) {
    try {
        context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
    }
}
```

You can also use following to check firstly if app is already installed:

```
public static boolean isAppInstalled(Context context, String appPackageName) {
    try {
        context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(appPackageName, 0);
        return true;
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I need it directly as I mentioned in my question.